# SharePoint 2010 active directory issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory

I am trying to create new user in active directory using c# and it is fine. When i try to add newly created user in SharePoint 2010 using c#, it will add user to SharePoint group but when i try to sign in with newly added user in SharePoint 2010 group. It will show access denied.

And also after creating user in active directory using c#, when i try to add user in SharePoint 2010 group with out of box way, newly created user is not available.

I am stuck in this problem. Please help me as soon as possible.

Thank you very much.

Comment: it could help if you posted the code you are using to achieve this.

Are you 100% sure that the user has been created in AD?

Comment: I found that user has been created but it is not properly created. so it is not available in web.EnsureUser("username") method.